# KVM and GPU of an HP Microserver Gen10

Tags: debian, virtualization, linux-kvm

I recently bought an new HP Microserver Gen10 with an AMD Opteron X3216. So what i am trying is to set up a Windows 10 VM and a Kubuntu VM for working from school as an example. I noticed that its really laggy even if i am connected through Rdesktop and in the same Network. So it must me the Graphic that is so laggy?

Well, since this Opteron  has an onboard GPU that is capable of two 4k Displays I try to share this GPU with the VM's in any way but how do I achieve that? I read about VGA-passthrough but i have to put a second GPU in there, what i can not do because of space reasons in the case (and money...), am i right?

So the Core Question is: **How do i "share" the GPU of an Debian KVM host with an guest VM?**

Regards, Nyno

Comment: The CPU just isn’t that fast. Rdesktop probably isn’t the best RDP client either. Or are you perhaps using the KVM VNC service?

Comment: Nope, that would be slower than RDP. I just take RDP because i want to access it from somewhere, i cant install any program. So RDP ist basically available on many PC's including Ubuntu (which is, what my school has.)

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but allow me to verify: This means you are indeed using Windows’ RDP server, not something the VM software provides, right? Because by default it doesn’t use the graphics card at all.